# SSRS excel report is exporting to user email but not opening?

Tags: reporting-services

There is a subscription which will export excel to user email every month. User can not able to open report as report is generating in .sheet extension instead of excel file. Moreover user do not have any internet access. will this be a problem with out internet access to open excel?

Please can anyone suggest me how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you may be using a data-driven subscription that is setting the name of the file with the `.sheet` name.

If you are using a data driven subscription, check the data from the query for the **subscription** (not the report's queries) and see if there is a value that is being used for the Extension.

[image]

Have you tried renaming the filename to change the extension from `.sheet` to `.xlsx` to see if it's an Excel file?

Comment: Thanks. when I rename the file to .xlsx file is opening and can see the contents. this is from my side. but how do I need to fix this so that user can able from their side. user means not within my office domain. user is in remote location. moreover user needs report only to email not with file share

Comment: Check the subscription to see if it's giving the name of the extension. If it's using a **Data Driven subscription**, the **File Extension** can be named with a **Static Value** or a **field** from the Subscription query (see pic above). Unfortunately, I don't have the Enterprise Edition of SSRS at my current job to use as an example so I can't give much more detail (only the Enterprise Edition has Data Driven Subscriptions).